# How to improve the speed of tables in Mathematica?

Tags: performance-tuning, table

[image]

As shown in the figure, I want to assign values to the defined very big function ff one by one, where ff has variables [t, x, v1, v2]. The speed of this Table operation is very slow, how can I improve the speed? (I tried changing the Table to ParallelTable, but the speed improvement was not significant). The speed of assigning values once is as follows.

[image]

```
CloseKernels[];
LaunchKernels[6];
rho1 = 0.;
rho2 = 0.;
sigma1 = 0.;
sigma2 = 0.;
kappa1 = 0.;
kappa2 = 0.;
tc = 0.;
r = 0.1;
theta1 = 0.1;
theta2 = 0.;
terminal = 1.;
deltatime = 0.004;
v10 = 0.1;
v20 = 0.2;
dimension = 4;
n = 1.;
dn = (2 n + 1)^dimension;(*和维数有关*)
dj = 10.;
dq = 10.;
collocation = Tuples[Table[(i)/(2 n), {i, 0, 2 n}], 4];
random1 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {dn, dj}];
random2 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {dn, dj}];
random3 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {dn, dj}];
random4 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {dn, dj}];
random5 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {dn, dj}];





omegapoint = 
Table[{RandomReal[{Max[collocation[[i]][[1]] - 1/(2 n), 0.], 
    Min[collocation[[i]][[1]] + 1/(2 n), 1.]}], 
    RandomReal[{Max[collocation[[i]][[2]] - 1/(2 n), 0.], 
    Min[collocation[[i]][[2]] + 1/(2 n), 1.]}], 
    RandomReal[{Max[collocation[[i]][[3]] - 1/(2 n), 0.], 
    Min[collocation[[i]][[3]] + 1/(2 n), 1.]}], 
    RandomReal[{Max[collocation[[i]][[4]] - 1/(2 n), 0.], 
    Min[collocation[[i]][[4]] + 1/(2 n), 1.]}]}, {i, 1, dn}, {q, 1, 
    dq}];

f[i_, j_, x_] := 
Piecewise[{{(1 + Sin[2 \[Pi] (x - collocation[[i]][[j]]) 2 n])/
    2, -5/4 <= (x - collocation[[i]][[j]]) 2 n <= -3/4}, {1, -3/
    4 <= (x - collocation[[i]][[j]]) 2 n <= 
    3/4}, {(1 - Sin[2 \[Pi] (x - collocation[[i]][[j]]) 2 n])/2, 
    3/4 <= (x - collocation[[i]][[j]]) 2 n <= 5/4}}];


psi[i_, t_, x_, v1_, v2_] := 
f[i, 1, t]*f[i, 2, x]*f[i, 3, v1]*f[i, 4, v2];
li[i_, t_, x_, v1_, 
v2_] := {(t - collocation[[i]][[1]]) 2 n, (x - 
    collocation[[i]][[2]]) 2 n, (v1 - 
    collocation[[i]][[3]]) 2 n, (v2 - collocation[[i]][[4]]) 2 n};
phi[i_, j_, t_, x_, v1_, v2_] := 
Tanh[{random1[[i, j]], random2[[i, j]], random3[[i, j]], 
    random4[[i, j]]} . li[i, t, x, v1, v2] + random5[[i, j]]];
df[t_, x_, v1_, v2_] := 
Table[phi[i, j, t, x, v1, v2]*psi[i, t, x, v1, v2], {i, 1, dn}, {j, 
    1, dj}] // Flatten;

dt = D[df[t, x, v1, v2], t];
dx = D[df[t, x, v1, v2], x];
dv1 = D[df[t, x, v1, v2], v1];
dv2 = D[df[t, x, v1, v2], v2];

dxx = D[D[df[t, x, v1, v2], x], x];
dxv1 = D[D[df[t, x, v1, v2], x], v1];
dxv2 = D[D[df[t, x, v1, v2], x], v2];
dv1v1 = D[D[df[t, x, v1, v2], v1], v1];
dv2v2 = D[D[df[t, x, v1, v2], v2], v2];
ff = dt + 0.5*(v1 + v2)*x^2*dxx + rho1 sigma1 x v1 dxv1 + 
rho2 sigma2 x v2 dxv2 + 0.5*sigma1^2 v1 dv1v1 + 
0.5*sigma2^2 v2 dv2v2 - r df[t, x, v1, v2] + r x dx + 
kappa1 (theta1 - v1) dv1 + kappa2 (theta2 - v2) dv2;

(*xVars=ToExpression[Table["x"<>ToString[i],{i,1,dn dj}]];*)
xdim = IntegerPart[dn dj];
omegapointbd1 = 
Table[{RandomReal[{Max[collocation[[i]][[1]] - 1/(2 n), 0.], 
Min[collocation[[i]][[1]] + 1/(2 n), 1]}], 0., 
RandomReal[{Max[collocation[[i]][[3]] - 1/(2 n), 0.], 
Min[collocation[[i]][[3]] + 1/(2 n), 1]}], 
RandomReal[{Max[collocation[[i]][[4]] - 1/(2 n), 0.], 
Min[collocation[[i]][[4]] + 1/(2 n), 1]}]}, {i, 1, dn}, {q, 1, 
dq}];
omegapointbd2 = 
Table[{RandomReal[{Max[collocation[[i]][[1]] - 1/(2 n), 0.], 
Min[collocation[[i]][[1]] + 1/(2 n), 1]}], 1., 
RandomReal[{Max[collocation[[i]][[3]] - 1/(2 n), 0.], 
Min[collocation[[i]][[3]] + 1/(2 n), 1]}], 
RandomReal[{Max[collocation[[i]][[4]] - 1/(2 n), 0.], 
Min[collocation[[i]][[4]] + 1/(2 n), 1]}]}, {i, 1, dn}, {q, 1, 
dq}];
omegapointbd3 = 
Table[{terminal, 
RandomReal[{Max[collocation[[i]][[2]] - 1/(2 n), 0.], 
Min[collocation[[i]][[2]] + 1/(2 n), 1]}], 
RandomReal[{Max[collocation[[i]][[3]] - 1/(2 n), 0.], 
Min[collocation[[i]][[3]] + 1/(2 n), 1]}], 
RandomReal[{Max[collocation[[i]][[4]] - 1/(2 n), 0.], 
Min[collocation[[i]][[4]] + 1/(2 n), 1]}]}, {i, 1, dn}, {q, 1, 
dq}];

max = ParallelTable[{ReplaceAll[
ff, {t -> omegapoint[[i, j]][[1]], x -> omegapoint[[i, j]][[2]],
v1 -> omegapoint[[i, j]][[3]], 
v2 -> omegapoint[[i, j]][[4]]}], 
ReplaceAll[
df[t, x, v1, v2], {t -> omegapointbd1[[i, j]][[1]], x -> 0., 
v1 -> omegapointbd1[[i, j]][[3]], 
v2 -> omegapointbd1[[i, j]][[4]]}], 
ReplaceAll[
df[t, x, v1, v2] - dx, {t -> omegapointbd2[[i, j]][[1]], 
x -> 1., v1 -> omegapointbd2[[i, j]][[3]], 
v2 -> omegapointbd2[[i, j]][[4]]}], 
ReplaceAll[
df[t, x, v1, v2], {t -> terminal, 
x -> omegapointbd3[[i, j]][[2]], 
v1 -> omegapointbd3[[i, j]][[3]], 
v2 -> omegapointbd3[[i, j]][[4]]}]}, {i, 1, dn}, {j, 1, 
dq}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

This is the code. I would like to obtain the result when the parameters "dj" and "dq" are relatively large, but as mentioned above, the code runs very slowly.

Comment: Please load Mathematica code that we can copy/paste/execute in our own notebook sessions. It is difficult to suggest solutions without studying your code. Thanks.

Comment: @Syed Thank you, now I have load the code.

Comment: As far as I see, the functions calling collocation[[i]][[[j]] are ineffictive.   Use local constants 

f[i_, j_, x_] := 
  With[{cij = collocation[[i, j]]}, 
   Piecewise[{{(1 + Sin[2 \[Pi] (x - cij) 2 n])/
       2, -5/4 <= (x - cij) 2 n <= -3/4}, {1, -3/4 <= (x - cij) 2 n <=
        3/4}, {(1 - Sin[2 \[Pi] (x - cij) 2 n])/2, 
      3/4 <= (x - cij) 2 n <= 5/4}}]];

Comment: @RolandF Sorry, the testing on my end is effective. For example, if dj=dq=5, I will obtain f[1, 1, x] and f[4, 1, x] as different functions, which means that i and j are valid in this function.

Answer (score 1):

At least the timing can be reduced by 1/5 by using functions instead of replacments inside the Table

```
 fff[t_, x_, v1_, v2_] = ff
```

[image: Output cell]

```
  ff /. {t :> omegapoint[[1, 1, 1]], x :> omegapoint[[1, 1, 2]], 
         v1 :> omegapoint[[1, 1, 3]], v2 :> omegapoint[[1, 2, 4]]}; // Timing

            {0.5, Null}

    fff @@ omegapoint[[1, 1]]; // Timing

             {0.109375, Null}
```

The other replacements can be reformulated as function evaluations, too.

Finally, a high speed module would use Compile with typed local arrays as data structures.

Comment: Thank you very much!